# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0 - An account required by the instruction is missing

Tags: web3.js, transactions, rust, phantom-wallet

here is the console error

I'm encountering an error while trying to execute a transaction on the Solana blockchain. The error message I'm getting is:

failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation…An account required by the instruction is missing

I'm using Phantom wallet to execute the transaction, and I have enough Sol in my wallet. I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. Can anyone provide guidance on what might be causing this error and how to fix it? Thank you.

```
 inpage_sol.js:150 Phantom - RPC Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing {code: -32003, message: 'failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation…An account required by the instruction is missing
inpage_sol.js:150 Phantom - RPC Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing {code: -32003, message: 'failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation…An account required by the instruction is missing
sendTransaction @ bundle.js:74787
await in sendTransaction (async)
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:74027
transferSol @ bundle.js:351
await in transferSol (async)
callCallback @ bundle.js:32361
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:32405
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:32462
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ bundle.js:32476
executeDispatch @ bundle.js:36620
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ bundle.js:36646
processDispatchQueue @ bundle.js:36657
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ bundle.js:36666
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:36826
batchedUpdates$1 @ bundle.js:51218
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:32209
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ bundle.js:36825
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ bundle.js:34331
dispatchEvent @ bundle.js:34325
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ bundle.js:34302
bundle.js:73899 WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (bundle.js:74818:15)
    at async bundle.js:74027:12
    at async transferSol (bundle.js:351:23) StandardWalletAdapter {_events: Events, _eventsCount: 4, signTransaction: ƒ, signAllTransactions: ƒ, signMessage: ƒ}
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:73899
handleError @ bundle.js:73984
emit @ bundle.js:22553
sendTransaction @ bundle.js:74821
await in sendTransaction (async)
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:74027
transferSol @ bundle.js:351
await in transferSol (async)
callCallback @ bundle.js:32361
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:32405
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:32462
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ bundle.js:32476
executeDispatch @ bundle.js:36620
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ bundle.js:36646
processDispatchQueue @ bundle.js:36657
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ bundle.js:36666
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:36826
batchedUpdates$1 @ bundle.js:51218
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:32209
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ bundle.js:36825
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ bundle.js:34331
dispatchEvent @ bundle.js:34325
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ bundle.js:34302
bundle.js:74818 Uncaught (in promise) WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (bundle.js:74818:15)
    at async bundle.js:74027:12
    at async transferSol (bundle.js:351:23)
sendTransaction @ bundle.js:74818
await in sendTransaction (async)
callCallback @ bundle.js:32361
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:32405
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:32462
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ bundle.js:32476
executeDispatch @ bundle.js:36620
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ bundle.js:36646
processDispatchQueue @ bundle.js:36657
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ bundle.js:36666
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:36826
batchedUpdates$1 @ bundle.js:51218
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:32209
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ bundle.js:36825
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ bundle.js:34331
dispatchEvent @ bundle.js:34325
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ bundle.js:34302
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your question, otherwise it's impossible to read.
Also, only providing the error it's hard to understand what is happening.

Example:

```
console.log('this is a piece of code formated')
```

You should also post the code that's originating the error.

Cheers,

Comment: const transferSol = async () => {

        if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();

             const programId = new PublicKey('7XyzLTMw7nBzoZnYoxauCzv11ruJee3HqjbxCyDfYb52'); //transfer sol
        const {
           context: { slot: minContextSlot },
            value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight }
        } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();
here is where it fails

Comment: here is the full app code https://github.com/zillerium/grizzlythonhackathon/blob/trevor/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

The error `An account required by the instruction is missing` generally means that the program (in this case, it seems to be the code around simulating the transaction here at https://github.com/zillerium/grizzlythonhackathon/blob/trevor/src/App.tsx#L258, where I consider you to be calling your own program that calls to do some SOL transfer) misses some accounts that it requires for processing. It could be the `keys` do not contain required accounts or that the provided accounts do not exist.